# Unknown Error in Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server

I had been trying to install weblate on my server, but when i try to run the command  `./bitnami-weblate... .run` it is giving me "unknown error"

```
Error: There has been an error.
Unknown error while running /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libstdc | awk '{print $4}'
| xargs grep -aoP 'GLIBCXX_([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)' | tail -n 1 | grep -oP
'([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)'
```

I had been trying googling that but don't find an specific error before.
Here is the [Screen Shot](https://i.gyazo.com/452399fcf293f03d931e3cb2c7bdaebc.png)

What does this error mean?

Comment: please don't post screen shots of you console - you can copy (even from a ssh-session) with <shift>+<ctrl>+c

Comment: Is `libstdc++6` installed?